# AWS Image Processing (Lambda vs EC2)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have an application that does block by block (x pixels by x pixels) processing (which can be paralleled) in Python. I just need advice on what the best approach is, architecturally.

1. Use Lambda function when the image is uploaded to S3, which does the processing (However, I'm confused as to how I can take advantage of parallelization or HPC, would it be invoking multiple Lambda functions for each part of the image being processed?)
2. Using SQS and EC2 (I'm currently doing research on this, but hitting a wall).

I just wanted to know what the better approach would be. I am continually researching, and I realize your time is valuable, but just wanted to see if anyone here had done something similar.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't think that there is one single best way to do this as it will be very dependent on your project, goals, constraints etc.

As an example, I've worked on a similar sounding problem: I had to process an SVG file depending on data provided to a Lambda function.

Initially I looked at doing something similar to (1) `S3->Lambda` but it didn't fit the problem domain because of the nature of the Lambda function being triggered by the S3 object-created event. It was a better fit for me to be able to call the Lambda function on demand.

Due to this I ended up calling my Lambda function directly via an HTTP request to [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) (`API Gateway->Lambda`). Potentially this could allow you to call different Lambda functions per part of image being processed but again it will be very dependent on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Why did you have to use API gateway, can't you call one lambda function within another lambda function? So thus manually invoking the lambda function without using API Gateway?

Comment: Yes you can, the initial call via API gateway was to trigger the lambda process rather than, for example, on S3 object-created event. Once the initial 'start' lambda function was called then other lambda functions called each other.